# Can't grab value from hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I get a javascript on the following code:

```
var teamOne = "";
var teamTwo = "";
var children = $(this).find(".team-url");
if (children.length === 2) {
    teamOne = children[0].val();
    teamTwo = children[1].val();
}
alert(teamOne + " - " + teamTwo);
```

The error is on `.val()`  The code finds 2 elements and then it can't take the value.  If I remove `.val()` I get it saying it is an [Object HTMLInputElement]

The error is

> Uncaught TypeError: children[0].val is not a function

Note:

I Know that I can get this code to work by doing the following:

```
var teamOne = "";
var teamTwo = "";
var children = $(this).find(".team-url");
if (children.length === 2) {
    teamOne = children.first().val();
    teamTwo = children.last().val();
}
alert(teamOne + " - " + teamTwo);
```

However, I am trying to understand why my first version doesn't work so that I can have a better understanding of these functions.

EDIT:

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 game" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <div class="team-details">Team Saturn
        <input type="hidden" class="team-url" value="TeamSaturn">
    </div>
    <div class="team-details">Team Datarnan
        <input type="hidden" class="team-url" value="TeamDatarnan">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: Because if you access the index of the jquery object like this $("something")[0] it is no longer a jquery object, and you can't use val(). That is why most of the guys said use .value because that is normal javascript. What you can do is this: $($("something")[0]).val(), it will change the element into a jquery object again.

Comment: Shorter: children.eq(0).val().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function `val` on a `HTMLInputElement` Object. As `children[0]` is not a jQuery element you can not use the jQuery function `val` on it. But you can use the native javascript for this:

You can use `teamOne = children[0].value;`

Comment: @Bagzli if `children[0]` is a HTMLInputElement it should not produce an error

Comment: You were correct, I think my JS might of cached when I did the test.  It is working with `.value()`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="value 1" class="team-url" />
<input type="hidden" value="value 2" class="team-url" />
```

JS

```
var teamOne = "";
var teamTwo = "";
var children = $('body').find(".team-url");
if (children.length === 2) {
debugger;
    teamOne = children[0].value;
    teamTwo = children[1].value;
}
alert(teamOne + " - " + teamTwo);
```

In your code "$(this)" is not in the real context, and I have changed it with a global search in "body".

[The JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o87ayapb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that children[0] returns the DOM element not jQuery object, so you need to use `children[0].value` instead. To get a jQuery object, you should use `.eq(0)`, `.first()`, `.last()` etc.

Second is that `$(this).find()` has no context. You could use either `$('body').find(".team-url")` or just `$(".team-url")`